# Uploading angular 5 project to domain using ftp and FileZilla

Tags: angular, dns, ftp, web, filezilla

I am trying to upload my website files to a domain so that it can be viewed using the url. I have seen examples but they are generally focused around uploading a specific html file that is the website. I have been using angular 5, so it is essentially a set of components. Using FileZilla, I have tried transferring over the project folder, and the website doesn't work. What special things do I need to do to transfer the project over to the domain so that it will actually open the website? Here is a screenshot of the project folder, where the src folder has tons of different components within it:

Comment: Have you tried building the project and FTPing over the output only? You can't run the src folder of an Angular project, it has to be compiled first.

Comment: what do you mean by FTPing over the output only? Do you mean to just ftp over the dist folder that ng build creates?

Comment: Bingo. You have to build your project, FTP over the contents of the dist folder and then have some kind of server running to serve the contents. You can't run it by just opening the index.html file.

Comment: When I sent it over to the domain using FileZilla, the guy who tests it and has the domain says it comes up with nothing, here is what he told me:
"The server isnt able to read the content as the index file just brings up nothing and the other files are just javascripts being called but by itself that does nothing"

And I sent over the entire dist folder...

Comment: I added a proper answer. Give that a proper go and see how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps to upload your angular project.

1. first enable  enableProdMode(); by doing production: true in environment.ts file.
2. now build your project by command > ng build --prod
3. You will get build code into dist folder.
4. Upload all files of this folder by FTP.
5. Now run your domain and it will work.

Comment: When I do that, the ng build feature doesn't work. I try opening the index.html file within the dist folder and it opens a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to put a full answer seeing as there's too much here to write in a comment.

As stated, you need to build the project. This is the most complicated step seeing as we are not sure how the domain/server is set-up on the other side. There's many different cases for how your index.html is being accessed so I'll just list them all.

1) Serving off of root: i.e. `myserver.com` loads you `index.html` file. Very unlikely to be the case or you would have solved this by now.

2) Serving off of a subdirectory: i.e. `myserver.com/ng-site` loads your `index.html` file.

3) No server: i.e. `D:\_Dev\ng-site\dist\index.html`

For the 2nd and 3rd cases, you have to set the base-href correctly for it to work when building:

```
ng build --base-href /ng-site/
ng build --base-href "D:/_Dev/ng-site/dist/"
```

If this is for a production build, i.e. requires minification and optimisation, you should also include the `--prod` flag:

```
ng build --base-href /ng-site/ --prod
```

Once that is done, you can FTP the `dist/` folder over. Note that is some versions of the CLI and how it is configured your output may be in `dist/project-name`. If that's the case then just FTP the contents of the sub-folder.

Troubleshooting tips:

If you or whoever is verifying it is having trouble with the site running properly, open up the developer console (F12 if testing in Chrome, which I recommend) and check what is happening in the 'Network' tab (you may need to refresh the page if it loaded before you opened the console). The `index.html` will request the various `.js` and `.css` files. If they have failed to load, it's likely because the base-href was set incorrectly. Open up the `index.html` file that the server is loading and look at the `<base href="...">` tag, you can modify it here to be the correct path of where the server should be trying to load the files from. Test it until you find the correct path. Once you do, copy that path and use it as the `base-href` the next time you run a build of your source.

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative answer, I am starting to understand what is going on. So I only did "ng build --prod", and the index file was blank. In the index.html file, I have "<base href="/">. I don't understand what to change it to or what to do for the "ng build --base-href /ng-site/ --prod". Are you saying that if my website was "website.com", then I would run:
"ng build --base-href/ng-website.com/ --prod" and do "<base href="website.com"> ? Or can you explain a very basic example?

Comment: If this helps you understand, I have it set up so that when running ng serve and opening "http://localhost:4200", it automatically redirects me to "http://localhost:4200/home" which is just my home page of my site

Comment: Last thing: If my dist folder has another folder with the project name within it which contains all of the contents as you said above, then do I drag over the project name folder, or do I click into the project folder and then drag over a group of the contents? Sorry...a little confused by your wording.

Comment: Only send over the contents of the folder that contains the `index.html` file. As for the base-href, you only need to set that if your website isn't being served from the root of the website. For example, if your local is `localhost:4200/home` and the hosted is `website.com/home` then you don't need it. If the hosted is `website.com/ng-site/home` then you need `ng build --base-href /ng-site/ --prod`. You don't have to manually change the `<base href="..."> yourself, the build command will do that for you. I only suggested changing it during debugging to find the correct href that works.

Comment: To be clear, you do not need to include any routes set by Angular in the href i.e. you don't need to include `/home` in your href.

Comment: So then in my case, I shouldn't need the "--base-href /ng-site/" part at all, right? However mine still isn't working. I appreciate this help

Comment: This is the error I see in the console when I open the blank index file Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /C:/styles.6379ff76ce8cb8a74e44.css:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.061525e915ca9cf9feed.js:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /C:/favicon.ico:1

Comment: I'm finally on to it. In the Network section, It has errors such as this with accessing files:


Request URL: file:///C:/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade


Which clearly that request URL isn't in existence. So now I just have to figure out how to fix this so that it references the correct files...but again I don't know how to do that...haha

Comment: If you're seeing things like `file://<file-path>` then it means the files aren't hosted by a proper server and you are directly opening the `index.html` file in a browser. For this to work, you have to update the base-href to the file-path to `index.html`. i.e. if your files on the server are `C:\path\to\index.html` then you should open up the `index.html` file and update it to be `<base href="C:/path/to/">` (notice that they are forward slashes with a trailing slash). Open the `index.html` in the browser again and it should be working.